# how to count upwards with multiples of each count

Tags: r, vector

I want to count upwards but have each number repeated, lets say 5 times.

example:

```
final_answer <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
rep(1:3, each = 5)
#>  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I got this, but is there a better way?

```
xvec <- rep(1:5, 5)
xvec <- sort(xvec)
```

Comment: yes. `rep(1:3,each=5) ` Have a look at `?rep`